# Image not displaying Django 1.8 ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-models, imagefield

Here's my models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2)
description = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
def list(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Views.py

```
def item_list(request):
    items = Item.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-created_date')
    return render_to_response('item_list.html', {'items': items}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('shop.urls'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djangoshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shop/templates/shop/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djangoshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': '',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/Users/grasbergerm/Projects/djangoshop/djangoshop/media/'
```

I've looked at the other posts on this topic and I've followed their solutions but I can't seem to get it to work on my end. In the page source I have

```
<img scr="/Users/grasbergerm/Projects/djangoshop/djangoshop/media/5_hat_1_2_b8a44Lz.jpg">
```

and if I go to that URL I can see the image but it won't show up in my page. I've just been stuck on this for way too long so any help would be appreciated.

Edit: this is my template:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <img scr="{{item.image.url}}">
    <br>
    {{ item.name }}<br>
    {{ item.author }}<br>
    ${{ item.price }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all:

```
image = models.ImageField()
```

you dont need `upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT` because it is default for imagefields.

and `MEDIA_URL` should be simply `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

and in your template, you need:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <img src="{{ item.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**:

you need to [tell your local machine explicitly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) to serve user uploaded files by doing this

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I made the changes you described and now my page source reads "<img scr="/media/Converse-Shoes.jpg">" but it's still not showing up.

Comment: @grasbergerm in local machine or in production?

Comment: It's a local machine

Comment: Still nothing, If I visit the url (127.0.0.1/media/Converse-Shoes.jpg) then I see the image but it still won't show up in the page.